# Getting value from IRow is slower while edit mode is on?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcmap

When I access a value in an `IRow` using `get_Value(index)`, it usually takes 0 to 1 ms. But when **edit mode is on**, the same operation takes 0 to 15 ms (most common values are 0 and 10 ms)! What could be the cause of this?

It doesn't matter if I use a filegeodatabase or an Oracle database (with SDE).

What we're using the `get_Value` for is our own ORM implementation (setting the Entity's property values to the ones within the IRow). Could there be a better way to do this?

Comment: A lot will depend on your cursor. Is it an Update Cursor, or a search cursor? are the features being recycled? You need to provide more information on what you are doing, and how you are doing it.

Comment: The problem (in our case) was that we were loading data using a `BackgroundWorker` (.NET). When the `BackgroundWorker` was removed, the data was loaded very fast.